# Incorrect rss encoding sometimes

Tags: c#, rss, windows-phone

I am working on rss feed reader project for Windows Phone. I use the construct below for reading feed in.
It seems to work fine for the 200+ feeds I track - apart for two feeds from NASA

```
"http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/TWAN_vodcast.rss"
"http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/TWAN_podcast.rss"
```

for which I get quite frequently problems. Not always and not the same feed, but a few times a week instead of nice utf-8 textual rss feed I get non textual stuff starting (in decimal)

```
31, 65533, 8, 0, 0..
```

The strange thing is that reading the feed at the same time with e.g. Chrome shows always good textual result.

Is there something trivial I am missing here? Some black magic that Chrome can do but Windows Phone cannot? Is there some way I can "fix" in my app what Windows Phone fails here? For compatibility reasons I am building for WP7.8 on VS Express 2012

(and yes, I e-mailed to feed owner some time ago but did not get any reply)

```
    public void GetFeed(string _RssUri)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += wc_OpenReadCompleted;
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(_RssUri));
    }

    void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.Result, true))
            {
                _feedString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Assert.IsTrue("0:60 1:63 2:120 3:109 4:108 5:32" == decodeStringContent(rssContent), "Feed does not start with '<?xml '");

            // doSomething(_feedString);
        }
    }

    public static string decodeStringContent(string _in, int _maxItems = 5)
    {
        string _decoding = "";
        int _i = 0;
        foreach (char x in _in)
        {
            if (_decoding != "") _decoding = _decoding + " ";
            _decoding = _decoding + _i++.ToString() + ":" + Convert.ToInt32(x);
            if (_maxItems > 0 && _i > _maxItems) break;
        }
        return _decoding;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about those particular issues you have had. I also have a feed reader app in the WP8 store and I haven't run into that particular problem when I preview a new feed. I tried with those two feeds and both worked ok.

I pasted a block of code that may help you. A lot of the code you won't need but it should give you a basis to start from.

```html
using FeedModel.Classes;
using FeedModel.Helpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace FeedModel
{
  public class FeedDiscovery
  {
    private delegate void HttpGetDelegate(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult);

    private enum FeedType { RSS, Atom, RDF }

    public void FindFeeds(SearchFeedsCallback callback, string searchString)
        {
            string url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find";
            string args = string.Format("v=1.0&q={0}", searchString);
            httpGet(url, args, (IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest sidrequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                        // End the operation            
                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sidrequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                        string subscriptionContent = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                        // Close the stream object            
                        streamResponse.Close();
                        streamRead.Close();
                        // Release the HttpWebResponse            
                        response.Close();

                        JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(subscriptionContent);
                        JArray subscriptions = (JArray)((JObject)jobj["responseData"])["entries"];

                        List<FDFeedItem> feeds =
                            (from f in subscriptions
                             select new FDFeedItem()
                             {
                                 Title = WebBrowserHelper.StripHtml((string)f["title"]),
                                 XmlUrl = (string)f["url"],
                                 Description = WebBrowserHelper.StripHtml((string)f["contentSnippet"]),
                                 HtmlUrl = (string)f["link"],
                             }).ToList();

                        callback(new SearchFeedsEventArgs(feeds)
                        {
                            Failed = false,
                            Error = "",
                        });
                       // return;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        callback(new SearchFeedsEventArgs(new List<FDFeedItem>())
                        {
                            Failed = true,
                            Error = "Failed",
                        });                    
                    }
                });
        }


    public void FeedPreview(FeedPreviewCallback callback, string url)
    {
      try
      {
        httpGet(url, "", (IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) =>
        {
          try
          {
            HttpWebRequest sidrequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the operation            
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sidrequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string subscriptionContent = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(subscriptionContent);

            FeedType feedType = FeedType.RSS;
            if (doc.Root.ToString().StartsWith("<feed xmlns") || doc.Root.ToString().StartsWith("2005/Atom\">"))
              feedType = FeedType.Atom;

            List<Article> articles;
            string title = "";
            string description = "";

            switch (feedType)
            {
              case FeedType.RSS:
                articles = ParseRss(doc, out title, out description);
                break;
              case FeedType.RDF:
                articles = ParseRdf(doc, out title, out description);
                break;
              case FeedType.Atom:
                articles = ParseAtom(doc, out title, out description);
                break;
              default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} is not supported", feedType.ToString()));
            }
            FDFeedItem feed = new FDFeedItem();
            feed.Title = title;
            feed.Description = description;
            feed.XmlUrl = url;
            
            callback(new FeedPreviewEventArgs(articles, feed)
            {
              Failed = false,
              Error = ""
            });
          }
          catch
          {
            callback(new FeedPreviewEventArgs(new List<Article>(), new FDFeedItem())
            {
              Failed = true,
              Error = "Failed to get articles"
            });
          }
        });
      }
      catch
      {
        callback(new FeedPreviewEventArgs(new List<Article>(), new FDFeedItem())
        {
          Failed = true,
          Error = "Failed"
        });
      }
    }


    public void GetFeedDetails(FeedDetailsCallback callback, string url)
    {
      try
      {
        httpGet(url, "", (IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) =>
        {
          try
          {
            HttpWebRequest sidrequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the operation            
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sidrequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string subscriptionContent = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(subscriptionContent);

            callback(new FeedsDetailsEventArgs(new FDFeedItem())
            {
              Failed = false,
              Error = ""
            });
          }
          catch
          {
            callback(new FeedsDetailsEventArgs(new FDFeedItem())
            {
              Failed = true,
              Error = "Failed to get feed"
            });
          }
        });
      }
      catch
      {

        callback(new FeedsDetailsEventArgs(new FDFeedItem())
        {
          Failed = true,
          Error = "Failed"
        });
      }
    }

    private void httpGet(string requestUrl, string getArgs, HttpGetDelegate httpGetResponse)
    {
      string url = requestUrl;
      if (getArgs != "")
        url = string.Format("{0}?{1}", requestUrl, getArgs);

      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
      request.Method = "GET";
      request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(httpGetResponse), request);
    }








    /// <summary>
    /// Parses an Atom feed and returns a <see cref="IList&amp;lt;Item&amp;gt;"/>.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Article> ParseAtom(XDocument doc, out string title, out string description)
    {
      title = doc.Root.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value;
      try
      {
        description = doc.Root.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "subtitle").Value;
      }
      catch { description = ""; }

      try
      {

        var entries = from item in doc.Root.Elements().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "entry")
                      select new Article
                      {
                        Content = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "content").Value,
                        Url = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "link").Attribute("href").Value,
                        PublishedDate = ParseDate(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "published").Value),
                        Title = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value,
                        Summary = WebBrowserHelper.GetSummary(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "content").Value),
                        CrawlTime = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/1970", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Author = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "author").Elements().First(i=> i.Name.LocalName == "name").Value ,
                        Read = false,
                        Starred = false,
                        FeedProviderName = "NewsBlur",
                        OpenMode = ArticleOpenMode.UseContent,
                        Image = WebBrowserHelper.ExtractFirstImageFromHTML(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "content").Value),

                      };
        return entries.ToList();
      }
      catch
      {
        return new List<Article>();
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses an RSS feed and returns a <see cref="IList&amp;lt;Item&amp;gt;"/>.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Article> ParseRss(XDocument doc, out string title, out string description)
    {
      title = "";
      description = "";
      try
      {
        //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
        // RSS/Channel/item
       var root = doc.Root.Descendants().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "channel"); //.Elements() .First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value;
       title = root.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value;
       description = root.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value;

       var entries = from item in root.Elements().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "item")
                      select new Article
                      {
                        Content = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value,
                        Url = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "link").Value,
                        PublishedDate = ParseDate(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "pubDate").Value),
                        Title = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value,
                        Summary = WebBrowserHelper.GetSummary(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value),
                        //Author = WebBrowserHelper.GetSummary(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "creator").Value),
                        Author = "",
                        Read = false,
                        Starred = false,
                        FeedProviderName = "NewsBlur",
                        OpenMode = ArticleOpenMode.UseContent,
                        Image = WebBrowserHelper.ExtractFirstImageFromHTML(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value),
                      };
        return entries.ToList();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        return new List<Article>();
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses an RDF feed and returns a <see cref="IList&amp;lt;Item&amp;gt;"/>.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Article> ParseRdf(XDocument doc, out string title, out string description)
    {
      title = "";
      description = "";
      try
      {
        //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
        // <item> is under the root
        var entries = from item in doc.Root.Descendants().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "item")
                      select new Article
                      {
                        Content = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value,
                        FeedUrl = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "link").Value,
                        PublishedDate = ParseDate(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "date").Value),
                        Title = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value,
                        Summary = WebBrowserHelper.GetSummary(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value),
                        Image = WebBrowserHelper.ExtractFirstImageFromHTML(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value),
                        OpenMode = ArticleOpenMode.UseContent,
                      };
        return entries.ToList();
      }
      catch
      {
        return new List<Article>();
      }
    }

    private DateTime ParseDate(string date)
    {
      DateTime result;
      if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
        return result;
      else
      {
        int i = date.LastIndexOf(" ");
        if (i > date.Length - 6)
        {
          date = date.Substring(0, i).Trim();
          if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
            return result;

        }
        return DateTime.MinValue;
      }
    }

    private string GetSummary(string content)
    {
      string lContent = content.Trim('\"');
      int contentLength = 800;
      if (lContent.Length < 800)
        contentLength = lContent.Length;
      string _localContent = "";
      try
      {
        _localContent = WebBrowserHelper.StripHtml(lContent.Substring(0, contentLength));
      }
      catch
      {
      }
      if (_localContent.Length > 150)
        _localContent = _localContent.Substring(0, 150) + "...";

      return _localContent;
    
    }
  }
}

​
```

```html
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace FeedModel.Classes
{
  public enum ArticleOpenMode {OpenWebPage,UseContent, Mobilizer};
  public class Article
  {
    private string _id;
    protected DateTime _publishedDate;
    protected DateTime _crawlTime;
    private string _author;
    private string _title;
    private string _content;
    private string _summary;
    private string _url;
    protected bool _read;
    protected bool _starred;
    private string _rawDate;
    private string _rawCrawlTime;
    private ArticleOpenMode _openMode;
    protected List<string> _tags;
    private string _feedProviderName;
    private string _feedTitle;
    private string _feedUrl;
    private string _feedId;
    private string _image;
    private AccountTypes _accountType;

    public Article()
    {
      _tags = new List<string>();
      _image = "";
    }


    public ArticleOpenMode OpenMode
    {
      get { return _openMode; }
      set { _openMode = value; }
    }


    public bool Read
    {
      get { return _read; }
      set { _read = value; }
    }

    public bool Starred
    {
      get { return _starred; }
      set { _starred = value; }
    }

    public string Image
    {
      get { return _image; }
      set { _image = value; }
    }

    public string FeedProviderName
    {
      get { return _feedProviderName; }
      set { _feedProviderName = value; }
    }

    public string FeedTitle
    {
      get { return _feedTitle; }
      set { _feedTitle = value; }
    }

    public string FeedUrl
    {
      get { return _feedUrl; }
      set { _feedUrl = value; }
    }

    public string FeedId
    {
      get { return _feedId; }
      set { _feedId = value; }
    }

    public string Url
    {
      get { return _url; }
      set { _url = value; }
    }

    public string Content
    {
      get { return _content; }
      set { _content = value; }
    }

    public string Summary
    {
      get { return _summary; }
      set { _summary = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
      get { return _title; }
      set { _title = value; }
    }

    public string Author
    {
      get { return _author; }
      set { _author = value; }
    }

    public DateTime PublishedDate
    {
      get { return _publishedDate; }
      set { _publishedDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime CrawlTime
    {
      get { return _crawlTime; }
      set { _crawlTime = value; }
    }

    public string Id
    {
      get { return _id; }
      set { _id = value; }
    }


    public List<string> Tags
    {
      get { return _tags; }
      set { _tags = value; }
    }

    public string RawPublishDate
    {
      get { return _rawDate; }
      set
      {
        Double seconds;
        _rawDate = value;
        try
        {
          seconds = Convert.ToDouble(_rawDate);
          DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
          _publishedDate = origin.AddSeconds(seconds);
        }
        catch
        {
          _publishedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
      }
    }

    public string RawCrawlTime
    {
      get { return _rawCrawlTime; }
      set
      {
        Double seconds;
        _rawCrawlTime = value;
        //try
        //{
        //  seconds = Convert.ToDouble(_rawCrawlTime);
        //  DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        //  _crawlTime = origin.AddSeconds(seconds);
        //}
        //catch
        //{
          _crawlTime = DateTime.Now;
        //}
      }
    }

    public AccountTypes AccountType
    {
      get { return _accountType; }
      set { _accountType = value; }
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! At first look your approach looks quite different to mine so it is not yet possible to mark this as a solution to my problem. However, the code you show opens some totally new strategies for me to try which may then lead to  my current nuisance fading away..It may take some time for me to experiment and refactor my code I am greatly appreciating your post

Comment: Thanks, let me know if it helps. The app is in the store and is called "Swift Reader". This part of the code is from the feed discovery search and preview page from the main menu if you want to check it out. You can use the trial version to test if this approach works for those two feeds.